# Sort a table using the total of other tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

2 tables: `memberships` and `week_scores`

**Membership** `has_many :week_scores`

**WeekScore** `belongs_to :membership`

Every membership has 16 `week_scores`

Every `week_score` table has a `score` column that has an integer from 0 to 20.

So just to be clear all memberships have 16 week_scores and I want to display a `leaderboard table` of all members of the group sorted by the total score of all their 16 `week_scores` tables.

It should look something like this

Username | Score

1. David  | 114
2. Rick   | 97
3. Mike   | 95
4. ...

The score column should be a sum of all the `week_scores` one user has so in case of David it was

```
week_score.score 1: 15  
week_score.score 2: 12  
week_score.score 3: 14  
...  
week_score.score 16: 9  
total: 114
```

If the name of the post is not good let me know.

Comment: Sounds similar, check if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813645/rails-activerecord-sum-then-order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is with an subselect:

```
subselect = "SELECT SUM(score) FROM week_scores WHERE membership_id=memberships.id"
@memberships = Membership.
  select("memberships.*, (#{subselect}) AS total_score").
  order("total_score DESC")
```

The additional column specified in the select clause (`total_score`) will be available on the returned membership instances as if it were a “real” attribute, so calling something like `@memberships.first.total_score` will work.

(Note that I extracted the subselect into a separate variable only to make the code more readable, it is of course also possible to have it inline instead.)